# Property 'constructor' does not exist on type 'T'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, next.js

I have a project with next and typescript and I have a generic recursive function in this function typescript says  Property 'constructor' does not exist on type 'T'.

this is my function

```js
export const deepClone = <T>(obj: T):T => {
    if (obj === null || typeof (obj) !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    let temp;
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        temp = new Date(obj); //or new Date(obj);
    } else if (obj) {
        temp = obj.constructor();
    }

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            temp[key] = deepClone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing here is caused by a slightly out-of-date version of TypeScript.

Narrowing generic types in functions has been quite unreliable for most of the time. But since [#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119) was merged in, generic types are intersected with `object` during control flow analysis when `typeof x === "object"` is used.

> In control flow analysis of typeof x === "object" expressions, generic types are intersected with object and/or null in the true branch (typeof checks for other types already produce intersections in a similar manner).

[#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119) was introduced in TypeScript version 4.8; so upgrading your version would be your best bet to resolve this issue.

```
export const deepClone = <T>(obj: T):T => {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }

    obj
//  ^? obj: T & object

    obj.constructor();
}
```

[Working Playground on 4.8.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCbGGAwgGxWDgF44AeAFQD4AKCAIwCsAuOSgShctOrgG8AsACg4YuAEsAZnHrNSJMsgCu%20fHAA%20GuDACeYYBBlymHOAEJFcAOSMmwBDGtmho8e6jAYyqMjh2AbhF3AF8RYPE7cLcxfC8dYABbMCCYyWM7STQYAENkBEMZABEcmGAXCPcxMuTSOGRgAHc4ErKTDgC4AHou6HqmltLgdtTQuGB8VGJpWTsKtPcasDq7ADokbKhlR2haDsq4MOEDqT7aDfQ4AGtgXSz-Znmq8RnaAHlmBxhVsCgIGH%20%20mAqwAFjlUG9GsgAAp-AywXTrHJqEwAGmutw4T2eVSWAG0broALp1LA4AhEEwE25E-YLcRHUIHTzeXwJZKpEJAA)